# How to close call kit when call doesn't connect but call kit ui is running in the background

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit

It happens many times that when call is started it doesn't connect and I can't figure out where it is getting stuck. When it happens the callkit ui is already started as I can see that green notification bar. How do I close callkit ui in this case when call hasn't been connected but callKit ui is running in the background?

Answer (score 1):

If call has ended by the remote side prior to connecting, you need to report the ended call to `CXProvider` object.

```
provider.reportCall(with: callUUID, endedAt: Date(), reason: .remoteEnded)
```

API details: [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider/1930701-reportcall)

EDIT

Here is an example how to report end the call if there is no answer:

```
provider.reportCall(with: callUUID, endedAt: Date(), reason: .unanswered)
```

Of course, you need to implement some timer which will call this in case some time had passed and the call hadn't been connected.

Comment: Sorry it's not the case. I'm aware of the case when call is connected and we have uuid to end callKit. In my case caller taps to call, calKit runs in the background but call doesn't connect. callKit continues to run in the background unless app is killed. I want to close callKit in this failure case.

Comment: At some point you need to end the call that has not been connected. I cannot help you fully since i do not have your implementation but, nevertheless, you need some timeout regarding the calling attempt. For example, when you request from CXCallController a start call action, you need some timeout handler which will invoke in (for example 60 seconds) and report to the CXProvider that the call like so: provider.reportCall(with: callUUID, endedAt: Date(), reason: .unanswered)