# How to close Callkit UI when call is not connected

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, callkit

I'm using Twilio Programmable Voice SDK. I'm facing an issue where call doesn't connect but CallKit UI starts. When I send app into background I can see the CAllKit UI running with green notification bar at the top.

There seems to be some issue with Twilio which twilio support hasn't been able to figure out and can't provide a solution.

As a workaround I want to close CallKit UI after a time interval when call doesn't connect.

I know how to kill CallKit UI when a call is connected but this doesn't apply in my case as call isn't connected at all.

My question is how do I kill CallKit UI when call isn't connected?

My issue is exactly similar to what is reported here [How to close call kit when call doesn't connect but call kit ui is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890160/how-to-close-call-kit-when-call-doesnt-connect-but-call-kit-ui-is-running-in-th)

Please read it again. 
**Call is not connected but CallKit UI is started and I want to close it. Note that when a call is not connected you will not get uuid hence you can't call disconnect.**

Comment: can you show how you are creating a call ? or how you are triggering callKit ?

Comment: It's the quickstart code available on https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift I've copied everything from there.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ViewController](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift/blob/master/SwiftVoiceCallKitQuickstart/ViewController.swift) code, it seems like the UUID should be stored in one of this two members:

```
var callInvite: TVOCallInvite?
var call: TVOCall?
```

In the case of an incoming call that has not been already answered the UUID is contained in `callInvite`, otherwise (i.e. outgoing call or answered incoming call) in the `call` object.

Comment: Call doesn't start from calling side hence no uuid is available. Only CallKit UI fires without actually triggering anything related with call.

Comment: In the case of an outgoing call there is in fact a point of failure: inside the `provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction)` function, if the call to `performVoiceCall(uuid:client:completionHandler:)` fails, the `CXProvider` will not be informed. You should add `provider.reportCall(with: action.callUUID, endedAt: Date(), reason: .unanswered)` just before `action.fail()` inside the completion handler of `performVoiceCall(uuid:client:completionHandler:)`

Comment: Sorry this function is never called when error happens. The control gets stuck in func performStartCallAction(uuid: UUID, handle: String) { .... It prints NSLog("StartCallAction transaction request successful") then it calls self.callKitProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: callUpdate) and nothing happens after this jsut CallKit UI is launched in the background. I see no further log beyond this.

Comment: Strange...if the StartCallAction transaction succeeds, then `provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction)` should be called. Maybe is the `self.callKitProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: callUpdate)` call inside the transaction completion handler that causes the issue, maybe it should be called later.

Comment: Any ideas on how to experiment with what you have described to see any affect?

Comment: Just try to comment out `self.callKitProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: callUpdate)`. If it works you can try to move it inside `provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction)`

Comment: Sorry Marco, it still didn't work. I commented and tested, still facing same problem.